# Thread not continue running

Tags: java

I have a following code as below:

```
new Thread(new Test1Runnable()).start();     // Line (a)

public class Test1Runnable implements Runnable {  

    public void run() {
       Test2Runnable task1 = new Test2Runnable();
       ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

          try {
              executor.submit(task1);

              while(true) {
                  if(task1.isDone()) {
                      break;
                  }
                  // Thread.sleep(2000);   // Line (b)
              }

              if(!task1.hasError()) {   // Line (c)
                  executor.submit(new Test3Runnable());
              }
          } catch(Exception ex) {
              if(executor != null) {
                  executor.shutdown();
              }
          }
    }
}

public class Test2Runnable implements Runnable {

    private Exception error;
    private boolean done;

    public void run() {
        reset();        
        doRun();
        done = true; 
    }

    protected void doRun() {
        try{
           // ...
           // ....
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    private void reset() {
         error = null;
         done = false;        
    }   

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    public boolean hasError() {
       return getError() != null || getNonSuccess() > 0;
    }

    public Exception getError() {
       return error;
    }

}
```

I have an issue when I run Test1Runnable at line (a) and comment Line (b) then the thread hang and not run to Line (c). If I uncomment line (b) or I add breakpoint at line (c) and activate remote debug the thread continue to run to the end as normal. Could anyone can give me some advice about this? Why the Thread not continue running? All threads run without any exception.

Comment: Does Test2Runnable.isDone() depend on a volatile variable?  It should.  Also, it's very wasteful to poll for a state change in a tight loop as you're doing in your while(true) loop.  To know when the task has completed, you should consider retaining the Future object returned by executor.submit(), and call Future.get().

Comment: Probably you're not well controlling the return value of tour `task1#isDone` method, thus having an infinite loop.

Comment: Enlighten us, why not wait on the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService.submit`call, instead of polling: see `Future<V>.get`? Polling is never a good idea to check for thread/task termination.

Comment: What other people are saying is probably true, you haven't posted the `Test2Runnable`class but your `isDone` method probably returns a non-volatile boolean flag.

Comment: If `isDone` is not synchronized, then there's no [read barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) that would cause it to return a different result.

Comment: How about method hasError() of Test2Runnable? Will error variable need to be declared volatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a race conditioin here, so result of the execution depends on timings, debug enabled, etc. The code posted is more or less fine, the error is likely to be in Test2Runnable class. I suppose there are some flags (isDone, hasError) that have visibility issues. Try to declare them volatile. 
Please add Test2Runnable code here and I'll be able to give more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks JK1. I have posted the details of Test2Runnable

Comment: Thanks. Now it's obvoius that fields in Test2Runnable lack proper synchronization to be correctly visible from the other threads. Try to make "done" and "error" fields volatile,  or synchronize all read/write access to them, it should do the trick

Comment: I have to poll isDone() method to ensure task1 is completed successfully without any error and then continue running next task. Is there any better solution to achieve this?

Comment: It works. I add volatile keyword to done variable and now it runs normally to the end. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: I use Callable instead of Runnable to avoid polling.